# Disable/Enable input-box in aspx with value from SQL

Tags: html, asp.net, input, disabled-control

Once again I cannot find what I want on SO, so:

**I want to disable input boxes in a repeater reading values from my MS-SQL if the value is False.**

Code snippet

```
  <tbody>
    <asp:Repeater ID="myList" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr>

            <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="<%# bool.Parse(Eval("Value1").ToString()) == true ? : "disabled" %>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="<%# bool.Parse(Eval("Value2").ToString()) == true ? : "disabled" %>" />
            </td>
```

It's the

```
"disabled="<%# bool.Parse(Eval("Value1").ToString()) == true ? : "disabled" %>"
```

I would like help with.

Comment: any particular reason you are using simple html control rather than asp.net controls ?

Comment: @KrunalPatil I guess asp.net controls would do. How would I go about with that? 

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled=<%#Eval("Value1")%>></asp:TextBox> 

generates a textbox but it ignores the Enabled value.

Comment: Actually you need to check this value on Rowdatabound, and then enable and disable the text box. Unless your Value1 return "True" or "False"

Comment: sorry it would be OnItemDatabound for Repeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Kruni Patil. Here is what I did:

```
protected void myList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

                TextBox txtBoxM = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox txtBoxT = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBox2");

                txtBoxM.Enabled = bool.Parse(row["Value1"].ToString());
                txtBoxT.Enabled = bool.Parse(row["Valu2"].ToString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: Good grief! I had no idea!